# Store a string in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to store a string `"hello"` in an array of characters `char arr[10]`

when I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[10] = "Hello";
    printf("%s", arr);

}
```

The output is generated fine.
But when this code below is run, I get an error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char arr[10];
    char * str = "Hello";
    arr = str;
    printf("%s", arr);
}
```

Why is that in the first case the string can be stored in the array and not in the second case?
Is there a way I can store `"hello"` in the second case?

Comment: Use `strcpy` in the second case.

Comment: Don't forget to `return 0;` in the end of `main`.

Comment: Note: arr is an array of char, str is a pointer to char. someFunction(arr) is similar to someFunction(&arr[0]). [This implies array decays into a pointer] and hence, use strcpy to copy contents from one to another.  `char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src);`

Comment: @SaucyGoat: It’s implied for `main`.

Comment: @Ry It may be implied, but it is always better to explicitly return a value.

Comment: See [6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1) An array is not a modifiable lvalue and cannot appear on the left side of an `=` sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strcpy is the way to do it, as noted above.  You get an error for

```
arr = str;
```

in your given code because you are attempting to assign an array, and C does not allow arrays to be assigned.  In your first part, the declaration you give

```
char arr[10] = "Hello";
```

is legal because it is considered an initialization (since it's in a declaration), not an assignment.  That is allowed.

C is not always a bundle of consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strncpy()` or even better `strlcpy()` if you are on a BSD system or macOS and portability is not the main concern.

In C, `char *p` means a pointer to a character string. While writing the following

```
char arr[10];
char * str = "Hello";
arr = str;
```

you might have thought that the character string stored in the memory location pointed by `str` would be copied over to the buffer `arr`, but C does not do this for you.

The code below does what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZ 10

int main(){
    char arr[BUFSIZ];
    const char *str=“Hello”; /* I used const here */

    strncpy(arr, str, BUFSIZ);

    printf(“%s\n”, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Use `strncpy` or `strlcpy` instead of `strcpy`. Documentation for `strncpy` is [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?strncpy(3)).

Answer (score 0):

To copy a string in C, use `strcpy`:

```
char arr[10];
char * str = "Hello";
strcpy(arr, str);
printf("%s\n", arr);
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>`, which is required for you to have access to this function.

Comment: `strcpy()`...really? why not `strnpy()` or `strlcpy()`?

Answer (score 0):

char arr[10] means that arr can be changed;
char * str = "Hello" equals to const char* str = "Hello", so it can not be changed.
so arr = str will occur error.
You should check the memory allocation mechanism in C.

Answer (score 0):

This is initialization of char array; there are special rules

```
char x[] = "foobar";
```

This is assignment to a pointer

```
char *p;
p = "foobar"; // char *p = "foobar"; initialization of pointer
```

There is no direct way to do assignment of a value to an array of char. You need to assign each individual element

```
char x[7];
x[0] = 'f'; x[1] = 'o'; x[2] = 'o';
x[3] = 'b'; x[4] = 'a'; x[5] = 'r'; x[6] = 0;
```

or use a function to do that for you

```
strcpy(x, "foobar");
```